# Powering a Sonoff Touch from mains

Tags: electrical, wiring

I purchased a Sonoff Touch which requires a three-way wiring system for lights, however, I only have live-neutral and no ground in my old house.

As you will see in the second image this is the circuit diagram of a livolo light switch which uses a half wave essentially to regulate the ac and use that dc to power its internals. I would like to know if there is a way to power a sonoff in a similar manner? Any other solutions would be appreciated! Thanks in advance
[image]

[image]

Comment: Sonoff touch link and as much information as possible would help. IF the ST uses the unswitched Phase to ground or phase to neutral voltage differential for powering then a 2 wire installation "would be difficult".

Comment: You have to install each of them according to **its** instructions and labeling (NEC 110.3).  The livolo does not appear to need ground, so you can wire it with only line, load and neutral if the instructions say that.  As for the *other* part you actually have, follow *its* instructions or send it back and get one that fits your application.

Comment: Unless there is exposed metal parts the user can touch, there is no legal need for a ground connection.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to install this product without a neutral wire.

First of all, the word "way" in switch terminology means something specific, and in your question I believe you refer to wires coming into the wall box.

What you require is a neutral wire, a live wire (line), and the continuation of that live wire up to the light(s) (load), which is what we're switching. To purely switch the lights on and off, you would only need the live and load wires, but because the Sonoff is an electrical device, it needs the neutral wire to draw power for its internals.

Despite the confusion over wiring standards and colour codes, this Reddit post culminates in the conclusion that it doesn't work in the absence of a neutral wire: https://www.reddit.com/r/homeautomation/comments/7l19a3/will_a_sonoff_touch_duel_gang_switch_work_with_my/